# High Voltage NMOS layout design in UMC130nm process using Cadence Virtuoso

Tags: switch-mode-power-supply, high-voltage, layout, nmos, cadence

I am required to design an NMOS switch in UMC130nm process which is capable of enduring approximately 10V VDS (drain to source) when the gate is 0V. And a current of approximately 50mA when the gate is open (Vgs = 3.3V). Below are the transistor list in umc130 library to which I suppose none would be suitable for my application.
[image]

My question is, given the spec above, is there any way to make a custom layout of such transistor (no matter how irregular it would be) without having them placed automatically by Cadence or would it be too far fetched? Below is a graph of a DC sweep on a single N_12_HSL130E nmos transistor.
[image]
It seems when Vds = 10, given Vgs = 0, approximately 40mA current passes through the transistor which I think is an indication of a catastrophe if manufactured right?
I also don't have access to the process documentation, there could be hints regarding this issue. So any help is very appreciable at this point.

Answer (score 1):

To handle "high currents", you will need numerous (10+ contacts at source and drain and at any metal_to_metal layer changes.

There may be special rules about enlarging the wells around the active/source/drain regions.

And control signals (to the Gate) may be constrained in how they overlap active regions.

These rules will be in the Layout Manual.